# Solve equation with inequalities for parameters

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve following equation:

```
Solve[{g^2 - gamma*alpha + alpha^2 - 
    omega*(omega*alpha)/(gamma - 2*alpha) - (omega^2*
       alpha^2)/(gamma - 2*alpha)^2 == 0, gamma > 0, omega > 0, 
  g > 0}, alpha]
```

I want to become an analytic, explicit expression for alpha, but *Mathematica* gives me only a solution with `Root`; for example, (there are more solutions):

```
{alpha -> 
  ConditionalExpression[
   I Root[g^2 gamma^2 - 
        4 g^2 gamma Root[
          g^2 gamma^2 + (-4 g^2 gamma - gamma^3 - 
               gamma omega^2) #1 + (4 g^2 + 5 gamma^2 + 
               omega^2) #1^2 - 8 gamma #1^3 + 4 #1^4 &, 1] - 
        gamma^3 Root[
          g^2 gamma^2 + (-4 g^2 gamma - gamma^3 - 
               gamma omega^2) #1 + (4 g^2 + 5 gamma^2 + 
               omega^2) #1^2 - 8 gamma #1^3 + 4 #1^4 &, 1] - 
        gamma omega^2 Root[
          g^2 gamma^2 + (-4 g^2 gamma - gamma^3 - 
               gamma omega^2) #1 + (4 g^2 + 5 gamma^2 + 
               omega^2) #1^2 - 8 gamma #1^3 + 4 #1^4 &, 1] + 
        4 g^2 Root[
          g^2 gamma^2 + (-4 g^2 gamma - gamma^3 - 
               gamma omega^2) #1 + (4 g^2 + 5 gamma^2 + 
               omega^2) #1^2 - 8 gamma #1^3 + 4 #1^4 &, 1]^2 + 
        5 gamma^2 Root[
          g^2 gamma^2 + (-4 g^2 gamma - gamma^3 - 
               gamma omega^2) #1 + (4 g^2 + 5 gamma^2 + 
               omega^2) #1^2 - 8 gamma #1^3 + 4 #1^4 &, 1]^2 + 
        omega^2 Root[
          g^2 gamma^2 + (-4 g^2 gamma - gamma^3 - 
               gamma omega^2) #1 + (4 g^2 + 5 gamma^2 + 
               omega^2) #1^2 - 8 gamma #1^3 + 4 #1^4 &, 1]^2 - 
        8 gamma Root[
          g^2 gamma^2 + (-4 g^2 gamma - gamma^3 - 
               gamma omega^2) #1 + (4 g^2 + 5 gamma^2 + 
               omega^2) #1^2 - 8 gamma #1^3 + 4 #1^4 &, 1]^3 + 
        4 Root[g^2 gamma^2 + (-4 g^2 gamma - gamma^3 - 
               gamma omega^2) #1 + (4 g^2 + 5 gamma^2 + 
               omega^2) #1^2 - 8 gamma #1^3 + 4 #1^4 &, 
          1]^4 + (-4 g^2 - 5 gamma^2 - omega^2 + 
           24 gamma Root[
             g^2 gamma^2 + (-4 g^2 gamma - gamma^3 - 
                  gamma omega^2) #1 + (4 g^2 + 5 gamma^2 + 
                  omega^2) #1^2 - 8 gamma #1^3 + 4 #1^4 &, 1] - 
           24 Root[
             g^2 gamma^2 + (-4 g^2 gamma - gamma^3 - 
                  gamma omega^2) #1 + (4 g^2 + 5 gamma^2 + 
                  omega^2) #1^2 - 8 gamma #1^3 + 4 #1^4 &, 
             1]^2) #1^2 + 4 #1^4 &, 2] + 
    Root[g^2 gamma^2 + (-4 g^2 gamma - gamma^3 - 
          gamma omega^2) #1 + (4 g^2 + 5 gamma^2 + omega^2) #1^2 - 
       8 gamma #1^3 + 4 #1^4 &, 1], g > 0 && gamma > 0 && omega > 0]}
```

This is not an explicit solution. I have also tried `Reduce` without success.

What can I do?

Comment: As a response indicates, you can just convert the Root functions into radicals. But actually the Root things themselves are explicit, and for many purposes they are better behaved than parametrized radicals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Solve[{g^2 - gamma alpha + alpha^2 - (omega (omega alpha))/(
      gamma - 2 alpha) - (omega^2 alpha^2)/(gamma - 2 alpha)^2 == 0, 
    gamma > 0, omega > 0, g > 0}, alpha, Reals] // ToRadicals // Simplify
```